# How can I ask Maven for a list of the default repositories?

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process

What command can I use to ask Maven for a list of the default repositories that it searches for its dependencies?  If no such command exists, where else may I look to find this default list?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

on the command line, execute

```
mvn help:evaluate
```

then, when prompted, enter

```
${project.repositories}
```

see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html

Answer (score 11):

You can output the [effective pom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) with the command

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

There the default repositories are listed.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-repositories-mojo.html) to show repositories for a specific build:

```
mvn dependency:list-repositories
```

or the full path, if you still use a very old version (<2.2)

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:list-repositories
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if you can't get past `validate`, which is likely to be why you're trying to debug the repositories in the first place.

Comment: Moreover, the `dependency:list-repositories` goal will list ALL the repositories used by the entire dependency tree, not only the repositories visible by the POM file.

Answer (score 2):

As a side-effect of displaying newer versions, the [`versions:display-dependency-updates`](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-dependency-updates-mojo.html) goal of the [Versions Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) also displays the names of the repositories that it searches.  To display the newer versions and the repository names, run

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```